# More idiomatic and elegant way of Clojure function

Tags: function, clojure, refactoring, idioms

I have a function which finds the least distance between nodes in graph, written in Ruby. I translated it to Clojure, but in my opinion it looks terrible.

The representation of data looks like this:

```
hash = {:v0 [:v1  :v2  :v3]
        :v1 [:v4  :v5  :v6] 
        :v2 [:v7  :v8  :v9]
        :v3 [:v10 :v11 :v12]
        :v4 [:v13 :v14 :v15]}
```

The Ruby function looks like this:

```
 def distance src, target, hash
    return 0 if src == target
    return nil if hash[src].nil?
    dist = 1

    if hash[src].include? target
        return dist
    else
        arr = hash[src].map {|x| distance x, target, hash}
    end
    arr = arr.delete_if {|x| x.nil?}

    return dist + arr.min if !arr.empty?
    return nil
end
```

And the Clojure function looks like this:

```
(use 'clojure.contrib.seq-utils)
(defn distance [src target h] 
  (if (= src target)
    0
    (if (nil? (h src))
      nil
      (if (includes? (h src) target)
        1
        (let [arr (filter #(not= % nil) (map #(distance % target h) (h src)))]
          (if (= (empty? arr) true)
            nil
            (+ 1 (apply min arr))))))))
```

Can you show me a more elegant and Clojure-like way of doing this. Those nested ifs are terrible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use sets instead of vectors and use `cond` instead of nested `if`s it looks, to me at least, a bit more Clojure-like:

```
(def h {:v0 #{:v1  :v2  :v3}
        :v1 #{:v4  :v5  :v6}
        :v2 #{:v7  :v8  :v9}
        :v3 #{:v10 :v11 :v12}
        :v4 #{:v13 :v14 :v15}})

(defn distance [src target h]
  (cond (= src target) 0
        (nil? (h src))  nil
        (contains? (h src) target)
         :default (let [arr (filter #(not= % nil) (map #(distance % target h) (h src)))]
                   (if (empty? arr)
                     nil
                     (inc (apply min arr))))))
```

It is also worth noting that clojure.contrib is quite obsolete now. Removing it allows this code to run on most any version of Clojure.

Answer (score 2):

Noticing that `filter` generates a lazy seq allows to simplify Arthur Ulfeldt's answer a bit without sacrificing performance by removing the `if`. Additionally, `contains?` can also be omitted, but in this case the increase of readability is disputable.

```
(defn distance [src target h]
  (let [arr (filter #(not= % nil) (map #(distance % target h) (h src)))]
    (cond (= src target)   0
          (nil? (h src))   nil
          ((h src) target) 1
          (empty? arr)     nil
          :else            (+ 1 (apply min arr)))))
```

Comment: `filter` might be lazy, but if you give a chunked seq to `map` then it will realize the first chunk when it's evaluated. Probably best to avoid that for this recursive call - could blow the stack if there's a cycle in the graph.

Comment: Never mind - `map` does everything inside a `lazy-seq`. So it should be safe - it's just that when you take the first element, it realizes the first chunk.

Answer (score 1):

Without any algorithmic changes you can shorten your code quite a bit (comments inline):

```
(defn distance [src target h] 
  (if (= src target)
    0
    (when (h src) ; nil is "falsy" so no need to check for it.
                   ; when's else evaluates to nil
      (if (includes? (h src) target)
        1
        (let [arr (keep #(distance % target h) (h src))] ; keep is same as map but drops nils
          (when-not (empty? arr) ; Same as above. Also empty? returns true or false.
            (inc (apply min arr)))))))) ; inc is used to increment by one
```

This could be shortened even further:

```
(let [arr (keep #(distance % target h) (h src))]
  (when-not (empty? arr)
    (inc (apply min arr))))
```

to this:

```
(when-let [arr (seq (keep #(distance % target h) (h src)))]
  (inc (apply min arr)))
```

Because `seq` returns `nil` for empty collections.

And as already mentioned by others, using Contrib nowadays is not a good idea.

Comment: Shouldn't the first `when-not` be `when` instead? Assuming that's the case, the repetition of `(h src)` is begging for a `when-let`.

Comment: @Alex true, my mistake, I will fix it.

Comment: Thanks, you are great. This way, I don't need to change my existing code. Also, I believe you've added too many parentheses after the first when. :)

Comment: @Wintre, yes it seems I did, I clearly need some sleep, I will fix that also :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are feeling seq-y:

```
(defn distance [src target h] 
  (if (= src target)
    0
    (->> src h
      (keep #(distance % target h))
      (map inc)
      (reduce #(if %1 (min %1 %2) %2) nil))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another suggestion. Calculate all the routes and then calculate the min distance:

```
(defn routes
  ([src target m]
     (if (= src target)
       [[]]
       (seq (routes src target m []))))
  ([src target m so-far]
     (if-let [near (get m src)]
       (if (contains? near target)
         [(conj so-far target)]
         (mapcat #(routes % target m (conj so-far %)) near)))))

(defn min-distance [src target m]
  (if-let [all-routes (routes src target m)]
    (apply min (map count all-routes))))
```